# How to replace internal PHP method?

Tags: php, c++, c, php-extension

I am messing a little bit with PHP and I want to replace method from internal class. I can do it easy with function (just change function handler in EG(function_table)), but doing so for classes (EG(class_table)) doesn't work. EG(class_table)->function_table looks like is not initialized correctly. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the [`override_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) method.

Comment: Isn't override_function() overriding only functions, not methods inside classes? I need to change method inside class.

Comment: Can you show us your code for what you have tried? A more complete example?

Comment: Just loop on EG(class_table) to get all the classes, then another loop on function_table on each class from EG(class_table). But this function_table seems to be empty/not initialized properly. And just to be sure: I am talking about php extension written in C/C++, not php code itself.

Comment: If you're talking about the C/C++ code you should be able to do a straight up override - hard to know since you haven't posted any code.